# How do i get the values of document.getElementsByTagName("...") in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

my code example:

```
var abc = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var def = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

I've got two `h2` elements and 4 `p` elements in my html file.

How can i get the the whole string of each element.
I've tried

```
var test = abc[0].nodeValue();
```

but that isn't correct.

Im glad for any help.

Comment: read the innerHTML or textContent?

Comment: maybe `innerText`?

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: abc[0].nodeValue is not a function``` you should do ```abc[0].nodeValue``` without ```()```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var abc = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var def = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(let h2 of abc){
    console.log(h2.textContent);
}

for(let p of def){
    console.log(p.textContent);
}
```

```html
<h2>h2 1</h2>
  <p>para 1</p>


<h2>h2 2</h2>
  <p>para 2</p>
  <p>para 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the value of the Node.

```js
var abc = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var def = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

const headerTexts = [...abc].map(node => node.textContent);
const paraTexts = [...def].map(node => node.textContent);

console.log(headerTexts);
console.log(paraTexts);
```

```html
<h2>h2 first</h2>
<h2>h2 second</h2>

<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
```

Comment: May you also explain why `nodeValue` didn't work?